# Is it possible to encrypt a file so that it can not be brute forced?

Tags: encryption

Is there any program or method that allows encryption that can not be brute forced or is it just that any encrypted file can be decrypted by brute force?

Comment: can you tell: what is `srrs`?

Answer (score 1):

The only encryption scheme that is theoretically impossible to brute force is a one-time pad. However, with any modern cipher, it would take millions to trillions of years to brute-force, barring the discovery of catastrophic new cryptanalysis, or -- in some cases -- the invention of quantum computers. This is widely considered Good Enough by those who do not count witches or galaxy-spanning alien civilizations among their adversaries.

If you plan to use TrueCrypt, you have more practical concerns, like software bugs, or a compromised random number generator, or a home full of cameras, or getting kidnapped/arrested and [politely asked](http://xkcd.com/538/) for your keys.

Why do you ask?

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty of brute forcing an encryption system is based on the degree of randomness produced by the key.  When a key is less than the length of a file, there has to be some type of reuse, and this means less than perfect randomness and thus some small susceptibility to being brute forced.

Thus, in order to make something truly brute force proof against an attacker with unlimited resources and time, the only option is a truly random key that is the same length as the input and that has never been used as a key on another message.  This technique is actually very, very old and is known as a one time pad (or OTP).  An OTP is completely future secure as long as the key remains secret.  Since the key is random and only used once, the input bears no resemblance to the output and "jfeidj" could just as easily be "attack" as it could be "dinner".

That said, attackers don't have unlimited time or resources, so practically speaking, almost any modern symmetric algorithm will provide more than enough security even at key lengths as low as 128 bits or lower.  128 bit AES, for example, while "technically" able to be brute forced would take so long trying to brute force that chances are good that if every computer on the planet worked on nothing but cracking the message, the sun would die and the solar system get sucked in to a black hole before they finished cracking the message.  (Provided there aren't any unknown flaws in the algorithm and that the key is properly generated.)  If you make it 256bit, the heat death of the universe will come before you successfully brute force it.

So practically speaking, just about any modern algorithm is secure against brute forcing with sufficient key length.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/01/21/shapeshifter/ and the wiki entries for Oligomorphic Code and Polymorphic Code.  I think ultimately, encoding is a means of representing infinite possibilities in a finite set... at the end of the day, there are collisions of the infinite set in the finite representation, ergo "decoding" via brute-force could lead to collisions that aren't actually the decoded file.

warning: I haven't slept in a couple of days.